# Line up "Back" text with heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What would be the best way of lining up the Back text (by placing it on the left hand side) with the Booking heading? I am having some difficulty overriding the Bootstrap theme. Furthermore if I wanted to have some text on the right hand side as well, how would I do it?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">Booking</div>
    <div>Back</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #0088CC;
    padding-left: 0em !important;
    padding-right: 0em !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
    padding-left: 0em !important;
    padding-right: 0em !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline !important;
}
nav > .container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d9nhqbyt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, `span`s are used in such cases - they are inline elements, while `div`s are blocks. Of course, that can be overridden by setting the display to inline/inline-block, or using floats, etc...

However, the best solution in your case seems to be setting the container to relative position, and then using absolute positioning to place left-hand and right-hand side elements.

So, something like this:

```
.navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9nhqbyt/1/

---

And here's an example using two floated spans inside the div (preferable approach): http://jsfiddle.net/d9nhqbyt/2/